# Rlinkedin API not connecting, getting timeout error

Tags: r, curl, oauth, linkedin-api

I am trying to use the linkedin API to access some data for a project. I am following the instructions provided by https://github.com/mpiccirilli/Rlinkedin . But no matter what I do I run into a time out error:

```
library(pacman)
p_load(rvest,ggplot2,Rlinkedin,httr,curl,devtools,dplyr,devtools)
in.auth <- inOAuth()
```

The console returns this message:

> If you've created you're own application, be sure to copy and paste
>   the following into   'OAuth 2.0 Redirect URLs' in the LinkedIn
>   Application Details: http://localhost:1410/   When done, press any key
>   to continue... Use a local file ('.httr-oauth'), to cache OAuth access
>   credentials between R sessions?
>
> 1: Yes 2: No

I click 1 or 2 and I get the same error:

> Adding .httr-oauth to .gitignore Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url,
>   handle = handle) :    Timeout was reached: Connection timed out after
>   10000 milliseconds

No matter what I try I get the same error, any help would be very very very appreciated.

Comment: upvoted for using pacman. No biases here.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?